# Invalid input type tel

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using an input type tel on a label control. It works fine on my local machine but when deployed on server it gives me error as below. Any pointers on what i am missing here.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `<input type="number">`

Answer (score 1):

Your server is using a different (older) version of ASP.NET/.NET Framework. You should either upgrade the runtime if possible or ask the host to do that for you.

Otherwise the only solution for you would be to use a regular input and then enforce the mask with JavaScript.